Why are login and logout times the same, and why is user information missing in my Flutter Firebase app?
I am developing a Flutter application using Firebase for authentication and Firestore for storing user data. I am encountering two issues:
The login and logout times for users are being recorded as the same time.
User information such as compound, ID, and full name is not being saved correctly in the database.
Code for User Authentication and Storing User Data:
SignIn Page:
import 'package:awesome_dialog/awesome_dialog.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/Home_screen.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/Registration_screen.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Screens/TableScreen.dart';
import 'package:proguard_86/Widgets/My_button.dart';

class Signin extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String screenroute = 'Signin';
  const Signin({super.key});

  @override
  State<Signin> createState() => _SigninState();
}

class _SigninState extends State<Signin> {
  var emailcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var passwordcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var compoundcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var FullNamecontroler = TextEditingController();
  var IDcontroller = TextEditingController();
  var logincontroller = TextEditingController();
  var logoutcontroller = TextEditingController();

    Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserDetails(String userId) async {
    final userDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').doc(userId).get();
    if (userDoc.exists) {
      return userDoc.data()!;
    } else {
      return {
        'FullName': '',
        'ID': '',
        'compound': '',
      };
    }
  }

  void _logout() async {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
       final userId = user.uid;
    final userDetails = await getUserDetails(userId);
      final userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').doc(user.uid);
      final logoutTimestamp = DateTime.now().toUtc();
     // Log logout time
      await userDocRef.update({
        "authActivity": FieldValue.arrayUnion([
          {
            "action": "logout",
            "timestamp": logoutTimestamp, // Use the captured login timestamp for logout
          'FullName': userDetails['FullName'],
          'ID': userDetails['ID'],
          'compound': userDetails['compound'],
         
            
          }
        ])
      });



      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, Signin.screenroute, (route) => false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 200,
                  child: Image.asset('images/pro85guard.png'),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 50),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: emailcontroller,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {},
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter Your Email',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: passwordcontroller,
                  obscureText: true,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {},
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter Your Password',
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () async {
                    if (emailcontroller.text == "") {
                      AwesomeDialog(
                        context: context,
                        dialogType: DialogType.error,
                        animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                        title: 'Error',
                        desc: 'يرجى كتابه البريد الالكترونى',
                      ).show();
                      return;
                    }
                    try {
                      await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: emailcontroller.text);
                      AwesomeDialog(
                        context: context,
                        dialogType: DialogType.success,
                        animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                        title: 'Info',
                        desc: 'يرجى الذهاب الى بريدك الالكترونى وتغير كلمه السر',
                      ).show();
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                    }
                    AwesomeDialog(
                      context: context,
                      dialogType: DialogType.error,
                      animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                      title: 'Error',
                      desc: 'يرجى التاكد من بريدك الالكترونى ر',
                    ).show();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 20),
                    child: const Text(
                      "Forgot Password?",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 5),
                Mybutton(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  title: 'SignIn',
                  onpressed: () async {
                    try {
                      final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: emailcontroller.text,
                        password: passwordcontroller.text,
                      );

                      if (credential.user!.emailVerified) {
                         
                          print('Full Name: ${FullNamecontroler.text}');
                          print('ID: ${IDcontroller.text}');
                          print('Compound: ${compoundcontroller.text}');
                          final userDocRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('signing').doc(credential.user!.uid);

                        // Log login time
                        await userDocRef.set({
                          'FullName': FullNamecontroler.text,
                          'ID': IDcontroller.text,
                          'compound': compoundcontroller.text,
                          'login': DateTime.now().toUtc(),
                          'logout': DateTime.now().toUtc(),
                        }, SetOptions(merge: true));

                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, Tablescreen.screenroute);
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, Homescreen.screenroute);
                      } else {
                        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.sendEmailVerification();
                        AwesomeDialog(
                          context: context,
                          dialogType: DialogType.error,
                          animType: AnimType.rightSlide,
                          title: 'Error',
                          desc: 'يرجى التحقق من البريد الالكترونى',
                        ).show();
                      }
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
                        print('No user found for that email.');
                      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
                        print('Wrong password provided for that user.');
                      }
                    }
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("Don't have an account?"),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, Registrationscreen.screenroute);
                      },
                      child: Text('SignUp'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


SignOut Method: The signOut method is defined to handle the sign-out process, including navigating to the SignIn screen.
 actions: [
        IconButton(
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () async {
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, Signin.screenroute);
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
        )
      ],

Login and Logout Times: When a user logs in and then logs out, both the Login and logoutTime fields in Firestore are being recorded as the same time. I expect these times to be different.
Missing User Information: The user information fields (compound, ID, fullName) remain empty in the Firestore database even though they are initialized when the user signs in.Firestore Document Structure:
Collection: signing
Document ID: user.uid
Fields:Fullname,ID,compound,login,logout
Screenshot of Firestore Document:

What I've Tried
Verified that the signIn and signOut functions are called correctly.
Checked the Firestore console to ensure the fields are being updated.
The lastLogin and logoutTime should be different times reflecting the actual login and logout times.
The fields compound, ID, and fullName should not be empty if initialized correctly.

Your code is setting both login and logout to DateTime.now().toUtc().  Why are you surprised they end up being the same, since you're giving them effectively the same value?

What is the solution to ensure that login and logout times are recorded accurately and user information is correctly saved in my Firestore database?

To implement that feature you'll want to write the logout value when the user logs out, rather then when they log in, i.e. in your _logout function (although I don't see how that is triggered).

I edited My code and I added logout function code
